# MySql: convert a float to decimal produce more decimal number then the stored in back.sql file

Tags: mysql, sql, database, floating-point, decimal

i want to understand this:
i have a dump of a table (a sql script file) from a database that use float 9,2 as default type for numbers.
In the backup file i have a value like '4172.08'.
I restore this file in a new database and i convert the float to decimal 20,5.
Now the value in the field is 4172.08008
...where come from the 008??
tnx at all

Comment: 5.1.x (i have made some try with 3 different version and the 'mistake' is the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the difference between float and decimal.  Float is a binary type, and can't represent that value exactly.  So when you convert to decimal (as expected, a decimal type), its not exactly the original value.

See http://floating-point-gui.de/ for some more information.

Comment: Ok i understand the difference of the types ...but please, explain me how the conversion from float to decimal produce more information (the 008) then the origin (4172.08)

Comment: It's not the conversion from float to decimal that produces the false precision.  It's the conversion from string ('4172.08') to float.

Comment: If you do, e.g. `SELECT float_col * 1.000000000000000` (where float_col is the float value), you can see this.

Answer (score 4):

> where come from the 008??

#### Short answer:

In order to avoid the float inherent precision error, cast first to decimal(9,2), then to decimal(20,5).

#### Long answer:

Floating point numbers are prone to rounding errors in digital computers. It is a little hard to explain without throwing up a lot of math, but lets try: the same way 1/3 represented in decimal requires an infinite number of digits (it is 1.3333333...), some numbers that are "round" in decimal notation have infinite number of digits in binary. Because this format is stored in binary and has finite precision, there is an implicit rounding error and you may experience funny things like getting `0.30000000000000004` as the result of `1.1 + 1.2`.